# undefined kafka components for Go kafka

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I was trying to install one of my go files. But I bumped into this error

```
C:\mygoproject>go install kafkapublisher.go

\#command-line-arguments
.\kafkapublisher.go:8:65: undefined: kafka.Message

.\kafkapublisher.go:10:19: undefined: kafka.NewProducer

.\kafkapublisher.go:10:38: undefined: kafka.ConfigMap

.\kafkapublisher.go:17:31: undefined: kafka.Event

.\kafkapublisher.go:19:26: undefined: kafka.Message
```

On my kafkapublisher.go file, I already imported the kafka dependency:

```
    import (
        "github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka"
        "log"
    )
```

even on my `go.mod` file

```
    module mymodule
    
    go 1.12
    
    require (
        github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go v1.15.0
        github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go v1.3.0
    )
```

I followed this documentation: https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/go.html

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SXEP.png)

Answer (score 14):

I was facing the same issues.

Kafka Go client is based on the C library. So setting flag `CGO_ENABLED=1` will enable go to use C libraries for kafka client.

Hope it saves someone's time.

Comment: Thank you! saved my skin, I was trying to build a go project that used confluent kafka connector in an alpine-go container. The error message was rather vague.

Answer (score 6):

When you build your image, use `-tags musl` (for alpine linux, @see github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go) and active `CGO_ENABLED` to activate lib in C because Kafka Go client is based on the C library librdkafka

In dockerfile :

```
FROM golang:1.16-alpine as builder

ARG GIT_TAG_NAME

RUN apk --no-cache update && \
apk --no-cache add git gcc libc-dev

# Kafka Go client is based on the C library librdkafka
ENV CGO_ENABLED 1
ENV GOFLAGS -mod=vendor
ENV GOOS=linux
ENV GOARCH=amd64

RUN export GO111MODULE=on

RUN go build -tags musl -ldflags "-s -w -X main.Version=$GIT_TAG_NAME" -o bin/main ./cmd/main
```

Note:
-***tags musl*** : if you want to use the built-in librdkafka
-***tags dynamic*** : if you want to use your own librdkafka.

Comment: can you clarify the reasons to use of buildkit ? And explain why you recommended to use the musl tag during the build of the binary ?

Comment: done, I remove buildkit (for cache docker), and i explain why use musl tag

Comment: indeed, downloading `gcc` and building with `-tags musl` is required to get the build going.

Answer (score 3):

I already figured out this one. I installed Confluent's Kafka Go Client.
Instructions are here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/go.html#

The library is not supported on windows though, so I had to use virtual machine (Oracle VM Box) to build and run my code.

I also needed to compile and install librdkafka before installing the Confluent's GO Kafka Client: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blame/master/README.md#L133

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure to activate `CGO_ENABLED` -> `CGO_ENABLED=1`.
- `CGO_ENABLED` is an environment variable in the Go programming language that controls whether the Go compiler includes support for calling C code.

Answer (score -1):

clearly dependencies are not being imported,

if you run the go build command, it will download the necessary dependencies and compile the code etc

try running `go build ./...`

Answer (score -1):

The dependencies have not been downloaded.

You can either use a **go get** to download the package.
Or Use

1. go mod download
2. go mod tidy
3. go mod vendor - This will create a vendor folder with the required    dependencies

Comment: Run your application and send me screenshot of the error. Try go run.

Comment: please refer to link on my description above. labeled "screenshot"

Comment: Did you allow these steps?                                                                                         git clone https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka.git
cd librdkafka
./configure --prefix /usr
make
sudo make install

Comment: You should install librdkafka on your OS.

Comment: im using windows. can i compile using windows? i was able to compile on windows using set GOOS=linux, but im not running this on windows. i deploy this on aws lambda/.

Comment: If you are trying to run this locally.  confluent-kafka-go is not supported on Windows. Says on the README.md as well. If your deploying this to AWS lamda linux. Make sure you install librdkafka on it. If you try running it locally it fails.

Comment: confluent-kafka-go is a wrapper around librdkafka. So you got to install it.